# DLLImports with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am very new to using Visual Studio 2013. Where should I put the DLL's Within the Microsoft Visual Studio folders if I want to call it from my c# application.

For example, I want to use [DllImport("QAUWVED.DLL")].

Which folder would I put the DLL in?

```
ConsoleApplication1
---- ConsoleApplication1
---- ---- bin
---- ---- obj
---- ---- Properties
```

Comment: Try creating a new folder "DLL" and put it there.

Comment: you should put on "ConsoleApplication1" and "bin" directory

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should probably create a new 'DLL' folder to store the DLL. But then you would have to `add a reference` of the DLL to the project before you would be able to use it.

Once, referenced, you should be able to use the import. Don't put in /bin or /obj. It will be cleared on each build you do for the application. All references will be automatically copied to the /bin or /obj upon build you do for the c# application.